# How do I send a bool value based on a checkbox from view to controller in asp.net

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

In my view I have a grid (from KendoUI) that I want to update based on the state of a checkbox. The idea is that I want to send the value (bool) of a checkbox down to my controller whenever it's clicked, and then call the service that is providing my data with the bool value from checkbox as parameter. From there, I want to refresh the list that is already populating my grid with the new data from the service call.

I've tried some ajax calls, but I can't seem to wrap my head around this.

Here's my index view:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="k-block">
            <div class="k-header">Unit List</div>
            @Html.CheckBox("mycheckbox")
            @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.UnitTypes)
            .Name("Grid")
            .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(p => p.Id).Groupable(false);
                    columns.Bound(p => p.Name);
                    columns.Command(command => { command.Custom("Edit Unit"); }).Width(160);
                })
                .Groupable()
                .Pageable()
                .Sortable()
                .Scrollable()
                .Filterable()
                  )
          }

        </div>
    </div>
```

And here's my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var client = new UnitServiceClient();
    var listOfUnitsFromService = client.GetListOfUnits(true);

    var model = new UnitModel
                    {
                        UnitTypes = listOfUnitsFromService.ToList()
                    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Hopefully, someone can help, as I'm completely blank when it comes to ajax calls :)

Comment: I have tried something along the lines of this:
`$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: "/Home/Index",
    dataType: "text",
});`

Called from the "onClick" in my checkbox html tag. Like I said. No clue about this :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you will want to do is create a controller action that accepts a boolean and returns a PartialView that contains all the HTML of your grid.

Your Ajax would then call that controller action, pass in the boolean and receive the grid HTML from the server.  It would then update the div that contains the grid with the new HTML.

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult Blah(bool someFlag)
{
    // Standard controller code.  Load a model.  Return a PartialView.
}
```

**Ajax**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    dataType: "html",
    url: '/Home/Blah',
    data: 'someFlag=' + $('#mycheckbox').val(),
    success: function (response) {
        $('#k-block').html(response);
    },
});
```

Comment: Mind if I ask; why a partial view as opposed to a view? :)

Comment: While you could return either, I personally prefer a PartialView, as it indicates the intent of the code, which is that I'm just giving you part of the HTML, not all of it.

Comment: Ok, so I've tried this, and the grid does not seem to refresh :( I've set my checkbox to react to onClick="refreshGrid()" which in turn is a js function, with the content you suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found my solution, at least for now.
Ended up passing the checkbox along with my FormsCollection into the controller and then doing my processing based on its "on/off" value.

My form was simply submitted by using the following line of markup:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="refresh" class="k-checkbox" id="refresh" onclick="document.forms.refreshForm.submit();"/>
```

Then, I styled my row, based on a "Disabled" property in my model, like so:

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.UnitTypes)
          .Name("Grid")
          .RowAction(row =>
              {
                  if (row.DataItem.Disabled)
                  {
                      row.HtmlAttributes["style"] = "background-color: LightGray";
                  }
              })
          .Columns(columns =>
              {
                  columns.Bound(p => p.Id).Groupable(false);
                  columns.Bound(p => p.Name);
                  columns.Bound(p => p.Disabled);
                  columns.Command(command => { command.Custom("Edit Unit"); }).Width(160);
              })
          .Groupable()
          .Pageable()
          .Sortable()
          .Scrollable()
          .Filterable())
```